# Exception handling for file deletion and showing a message using ValidationMessage()

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

This question continues from a previous question I posted at the link below:

[Passing a filename to a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39306108/c-sharp-mvc-based-cms-problems-deleting-file)

In summary: I am trying to delete a file. I now have all the necessary functionality working thanks to the answer at the above post. However, occasionally, if the file was in use (which would happen if I downloaded the file prior to deleting for example), I would get an IOException.

I want to handle this exception and display a message back to the user when this happens.

I tried debugging the jQuery code, but whenever I put a breakpoint on it, I start skipping through 1000's of lines of jQuery libraries. So as a quick alternative I just put alerts everywhere.

I discovered that most of this code is not being executed - so I put comments beside where I think I should be seeing messages but am not. So as a result I am unable to debug or figure out what the code is supposed to be doing.

So my first question is how to get the exception showing. It seems that even though this is Ajax, the whole page still refreshes, which to me is not the expected behaviour for Ajax calls (so if an error is showing its maybe lost when the page refreshes). However, with all the alerts, I should see the error somewhere, but I am not. I have purposefully altered the working code to always throw an exception for now. Again, the delete functionality works, its the error reporting that fails.

My next question is to have a brief explanation of why each section of the code (where highlighted) is needed as I don't know why those sections exist and I cant figure it out because I cant debug into or show alerts for them.

Below is the index view and the code in question:

```
@model IEnumerable<FileInfo>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "File List";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>@Html.ActionLink("Upload", "Upload")</p>
<p>@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })</p>
<p>@Html.ValidationMessage("Name", new { @class = "text-danger" })</p>
<span class="message text-danger"></span>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>File Name</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (FileInfo file in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@file.Name</td>
            <td>
                <form class="deleteform">
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    <input type="hidden" name="fileName" value="@file.Name" />
                    <input type="submit" value="delete" />
                </form>
            </td>
            <td>@Html.ActionLink("Download", "Download", new { fileName = file.Name })</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready()
        {
            var url = '@Url.Action("Delete", "FileManagement")';

            $('.deleteform').submit(function ()
            {
                alert(".deleteform.submit entered...");//This alert shows

                return confirm("are you sure ...");//This alert shows

                var formData = $(this).serialize();
                alert(formData);//This does NOT show.

                var row = $(this).closest('tr');
                alert(row);//This does NOT show.

                $.post(url, formData, function (response)
                {
                    alert("$.post() entered...");//This does NOT show.
                    alert(response);//This does NOT show.
                    if (response)
                    {
                        alert("response true");//This does NOT show.
                        alert(response);//This does NOT show.
                        //row.remove(); //This code actually works even though the alert above does not show.
                    } else
                    {
                        alert("response false");//This does NOT show. - I dont know what this section of code is for.
                        //alert("Error 1 - display message");
                        // Oops - display message?
                    }
                    alert("$.post() finished...");//This does NOT show.

                }).fail(function (response)
                {
                    alert("$.fail() entered...");//This does NOT show. - I dont know what this section of code is for.
                    alert("Error 2 - display another message");//This does NOT show.
                    // Oops

                    alert("$.fail() finished...");//This does NOT show.
                });
                return false; // cancel the default submit

                alert(".deleteform.submit finished...");//This does NOT show.
            });
        }
    </script>
}
```

Below is the controller for this view and the delete actions:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/UserFiles"));
        List<FileInfo> files = dirInfo.GetFiles().ToList();

        return View(files);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Delete(string fileName)
    {
        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/UserFiles"), fileName);

        if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
        {
            try
            {
                //System.IO.File.Delete(path);
                throw new IOException("Hello - Test Message...");
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                Response.StatusCode = 500;
                Response.StatusDescription = e.Message;
                //ModelState.AddModelError("Name", e.Message);
            }
        }
        else
            return Json(null);
        //return HttpNotFound();

        return Json(true);
        //return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

I would appreciate any help on this.

Comment: You cant use `return confirm("are you sure ...")`  - that is exiting the method (you would only use that if you were handling the default submit, but in your case your cancelling it and making an ajax call instead). Instead use `if (confirm("....") { // make you ajax call }`

Comment: I figured out the fail happens when status code is 500, and how to get the message to the front end (so I can figure out how to display it later). I also figured out the if(response) = true part, that's when everything goes well. The only part I cant see a use for is the if(response)...else part. I assume anything other than 200 is going to send us to the .fail part. so why do we need the else part and indeed, without the else, why even the if(response)? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: You don't need it if you want to return the details of the error (the code I gave in the previous question was assuming you would use `return Json(null);` if the file could not be deleted (and in the `if(response)` block you would just display a _"could not delete file"_ general error - its generally not good to expose the specific details of the error - its just gives malicious users extra info about potential vunerabilities in your app)

Comment: @StephenMuecke - So...Thanks to changing the return(confirm) line as you suggested to an if(confirm). I managed to figure out the rest of the issues and display the error messages. If you would like to put this as the answer when you get a chance, I will accept. As always Stephen, thanks again for all your help and suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `return confirm("are you sure ...");` in the `.submit()` handler because it either returns `false` which cancels everything, or it returns `true` in which case you will be making a normal submit. In either case, it exits the function.

You need to change the script to

```
$('.deleteform').submit(function () {
    if (confirm("....") {
        // make you ajax call here
    }
    return false; 
});
```

You also need to modify your controller code. Currently your last line (`return Json(true);`) can never be executed, and the code in the `if` block is always returning an error, so will always go to the `.fail()` function. Generally, you should not return the specific details of exceptions your code throws (this just exposes it to malicious users) and it is better to return a more general error, or return `null` and hard code the error message in the script. There are various ways you can handle this, including

```
try
{
   // delete the file
   return Json(true); // to indicate success
}
catch (.... )
{
    return Json(null); // indicate failure
}
```

which in the script means

```
if (response) { // this will be executed if you returned true
    ... // delete the row
} else { // this will be executed if you returned null
    ... // display a message to the user
}
```

and the `.fail()` function will be executed if an exception is throw on the server which you have not caught.

Alternatively you could return on object with properties for `Success` and `Message` which gives you a bit more control over the message, for example

```
return Json(new { Success = true });
// or
return Json(new { Success = false, Message = "The file does not exist"});
// or
retrn Json(new { Success = false, Mesage = "The file is in use, please try again late" });
```

and the in the script

```
$.post(url, formData, function (response) {
    if (response.Success == 'False') {
        var message = response.Message; // display it
```

Comment: Thanks again Stephen. - Its a lot clearer now. I'll go ahead and implement it with your suggestions shortly. I have also started the process of implementing proper roles and user management for handling the security concerns a bit better. I still have yet to add logging for proper error handling such as this situation requires (as opposed to giving all the errors to the end user). I'm making great progress, and a great part is due to your help. Thanks again Stephen.